# Laravel 5.4 producing public/uploads/avatar folder

Tags: laravel, upload, laravel-5.4, avatar

I have a fundraising platform built with Laravel 5.4. I've been successful in removing the public from the URL and hiding both the .env and composer.json files from view, but I can't upload an avatar to the upload/avatar folder from the admin or user account because Laravel produces a public/uploads/avatar folder and uploads the avatar into it instead of into the upload/avatar folder where it needs to go.

I have tried updating routes and usercontroller but to no avail. I'm not sure where to look now.

Can someone help me out with telling me where I go to change the code so Laravel no longer produces a public/uploads/avatar folder when I upload an avatar so the avatar goes into the upload/avatar folder instead?

Thanks.

Comment: try checking at config/filesystems.php.

care to show your code for the upload?

Comment: Delete the symbolic link between storage/public and public folders

Comment: I don't have the code, I'm trying to find the code within Laravel 5.4 to change the action of Laravel producing a public/uploads/avatar folder so the avatars upload to the upload/avatar folder.

Comment: 'Delete the symbolic link between storage/public and public folders' Ok thanks I will look around for that.

Comment: ok, so, I can't find where the symbolic link between storage/public and public folders is. I have basically no experience with Laravel so please explain to me in a little more detail. Thanks.

Comment: Here is my code: 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            //'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'root' => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',

Comment: I mean the store code. how do you store the file. something like $request->file('file')->store('/upload');

Answer (score 0):

In Filesystems.php

Change this:

```
'public' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root'   => public_path(),
],
```

To this:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => '/',
],
```

Comment: Noob Beginner I changed the code to you post and nothing has changed. Laravell still reproduces the public folder. Thanks any way.

Comment: @Razoo where does it reproduce the public folder? 

run composer dumpautoload then try again.

Is it uploading to the public/public/uploads or public/uploads ?

Comment: It reproduces the public folder in the root. Sorry Noob Beginner but I am a true noob beginner. This is my first time working with Laravel so I'm not familiar with composer.

Comment: just run 'composer dumpautoload' in command line at your laravel project root directory

Comment: @ Jerico Pulvera, apparently running composer is beyond my abilities at the moment. It's ok though. I just added the app.url to the templates img src elements and it works fine for user, but not admin.

 

<img src="{{ config( 'app.url' ) }}{{ $user_avatar }}" class="profile-img">

Comment: @Razoo what is stored in your $user_avatar variable?